# HashCode Loop Calling : OneToMany JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I want to excute this method :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Project> listProjects() {

    return ps.findAllProjects();
}
```

And in my **DAO** I have :

```
@Repository
public interface ProjectDAO extends JpaRepository<Project, Long> {
    List<Project> findAllProjectsByShowableTrue();  }
```

And in my entity :

**1. Project :**

```
@Transactional
@Entity
public class Project implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String name;

private boolean showable = true;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="project", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Collaborator> collaborators = new HashSet<>();

@Override
public int hashCode() {
final int prime = 31;
int result = 1;
result = prime * result + ((collaborators == null) ? 0 : collaborators.hashCode());
result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
      }
//Getters & setters        
}
```

**2. Collaborator :**

```
@Entity
public class Collaborator implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "ProjectID" , nullable = true)
private Project project;

@Override
public int hashCode() {
      final int prime = 31;
      int result = 1;
      result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
      result = prime * result + ((project == null) ? 0 : project.hashCode());
return result;
}
//Getters & setters      
}
```

But i'm getting this Error :

```
HTTP Status 500 - Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError

root cause
java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.available(Unknown Source)
java.net.SocketInputStream.available(Unknown Source)
.........
gestionprojet.java.entities.beans.Project.hashCode(Project.java:179)
gestionprojet.java.entities.beans.Collaborator.hashCode(Collaborator.java:88)
```

Now when the collaborator table is empty : the request runs perfectly but when I add a collaborator to a project all related requests are broken.

*P.S :* HashCode() & Equals() methods are generated automatically.

Any help would be appreciated. Tank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Project` class is calling `collaborators.hashCode()` and your `Collaborators` class is calling `project.hashCode()`.

So when a project has a collaborator you get an infinite loop, because `Project` calls `Collaborator`, `Collaborator` calls `Project` and so on...

Comment: then what you suggest ?

Comment: I would take the `Project` out of the `Collaborator` `hashCode` and `equals` since, i suppose it will be a mutable field. A `Collaborator`is still the same `Collaborator` whether he is in `Project`A or B.